# Laravel Failed to open stream warning in Ubuntu 14

Tags: laravel-4, migration, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04

I am new in Ubuntu and try to migrate a laravel app to ubuntu.
Please take a look at below steps done.

1.Copied my laravel project and upload database.

2.Started my Xampp server and pointed my laravel app in browser, it showing error like.

```
Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

When trying to update the composer with terminal throwing error like ***Mcrypt extension is required.***

Please give me a solution for it.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Mcrypt extension, to install:

`sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`

Then:
`sudo updatedb && locate mcrypt.ini`

Should show it located at /etc/php5/mods-available

`locate mcrypt.so`

Then edit mcrypt.ini with

chang th`extension=mcrypt.so` to `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so` (or whatever is the location of your mcrypt.so.

Next, create the symbol links

`ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini`

and finally, restart apache
`service apache2 restart`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install the mcrypt PHP extension.